# Why GetSecurityInfo succeeds on INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE?

Tags: winapi, nt-security

I find that [GetSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getsecurityinfo) succeeds when passed `0xFFFFffff`(`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`). That's weird, because MSDN seems not to mention such case.

From Visual Studio debugger, we can clearly see such behavior, both on Win7 and Win10.

`GetSecurityInfo` succeeds with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and returns a meaningful `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`(SD).

**The question is, I don't know, which securable-object is this SD referring to.**

[image]

I happen to have a small program [NtfsOwner1](https://github.com/chjfth/trivials/blob/b0b9b7ba6ac3e27bd49e8c0ed635640e83cf3bdc/mswin/NtfsOwner1/NtfsOwner1.cpp) that can demonstrate this. It shows owner-SID of the returned SD.

Some sample output below:

Run as user chj(member of Adminitrators group), non-privileged:

[image: Run as user chj, non-privileged]

Run as user chj(member of Adminitrators group), privileged:

[image: Run as user chj, privileged]

Run as Administrator himself:

[image: Run as Administrator himself]

Comment: The value `-1` is the pseudo handle returned by GetCurrentProcess()

Comment: Thank you, quite rational, then I'm getting the SD of current process.